# ADO Failing Second time through a loop

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, adodb

I have an Access application (Access Front-end, SQL backend using Linked tables) and I'm having this issue:
The user enters in a part number. Then they enter in a quantity. New business logic says I have to check this part number against a table, to see if we have quoted it to a customer within the past year. If we have, we can quote it now; if not, we have to reject the part.
When the program was originally written, they used a datasheet format to allow the user to copy from Excel a list of parts, paste them into the datasheet, and then copy and paste in a list of quantities. Once the quantity is entered/pasted for a line, that line is processed.
If I manually enter in a part number, then the quantity, the needed code checks to see if the part number has been quoted within the last year, and everything is peachy.
But if I copy and paste in a list of parts, the first time through the process it works fine; but every other time fails.
Here's the basic code:

```vb
Dim cn21 As ADODB.Connection
Set cn21 = New ADODB.Connection
Dim strsql21 As String
Dim cm21 As New ADODB.Command
Dim rs21 As New ADODB.Recordset


' gblODBCString = "ODBC;Description=PartsPortalsSql;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=db-TEST-partsptl-primary;Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=Microsoft Office 2010;DATABASE=PartsPortalSQL;"

cn21.Open gblODBCString


cm21.ActiveConnection = cn21

' All I want to know is how many records there are for this part within the last year...

strsql21 = "Select count(*) from tblQuoteDetail tqd INNER JOIN tblQuotes tq on tqd.quoteid = tq.quoteid WHERE " _
   & " tqd.qdetailpartno = '" & Me.QDetailPartNo & "' AND tq.quotesentdate >= '" & OneYearAgo & "' AND tqd.qdetailunitprice > 0"
cm21.CommandText = strsql21

Set rs21 = New ADODB.Recordset
Set rs21 = cn21.Execute(strsql21, varparams, adCmdText)

If rs21(0) = 0 Then   ' nothing found! can't be escalated...

blah blah blah...

end if

' done with this part... clean up

Set cm21 = Nothing
rs21.Close
Set rs21 = Nothing
Set cn21 = Nothing
```

Then it will return here when it gets to the next part...
But if i do it manually, it works fine. But when it is running through the loop of parts, it gets to the:
Set rs21 = cn21.Execute(strsql21, varparams, adcmdtext) 
line
and takes about 30 seconds to 'process/time out', and then the rs21(0) returns "Run-time error '3265': Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal."

I've verified every field in the sql query is correctly populated. I've never run into this issue before.

Other things I've attempted - use DAO instead of ADODB... no luck...

If anyone has any suggestions I'm all ears... short of blowing it up... I'm in the testing phase of a replacement version, that doesn't use that copy/paste functionality. But that's still a month or two away from production.

Thanks

Access 2016, Linked tables to Microsoft SQL Server 2016 I believe...
Windows 10 64 bit
Also running on a VPN, connected to a VDI.

Comment: Please use proper parameters instead of writing SQL injection honeypots. You're going to all the trouble of creating ADODB.Command, go on and use its .Parameters instead of sloppy and dangerous string concatenation...

Comment: are you sure youre using the right command for a recordset?

Comment: So this 'fixes' the problem, somewhat... I changed the sql statement to pull the detailid field for the records it finds, instead of trying to have it count how many records it found. All I care about is if there is at least one record within the last year. So I changed the If statement to look out for the EOF condition, or if the detailid = 0, and it works fine... not sure why it doesn't like the count command...

Answer (score 1):

I htink youre using the wrong commands to check for recordsets. I could be wrong as I dont use ADO as much as I should, but here is my template for it if you thin itll help

```
'needs the MSO AtiveX Data Objects Library
Dim vbSql As String, cnnstr  as string
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

vbSql = "SELECT ;"
Set cnn = New Connection
cnnstr = ""
cnn.Open cnnstr
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rs.Open vbSql, cnn
cnn.Close
Set cnn = Nothing
```